# How to save credit card and make re-bill based on varying amount and frequency (not recurring billing)) using paypal

Tags: paypal

I want to save credit card info of customers and later I want to bill them on different time period. Billing amount and frequency may change. Is this possible via paypal??

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll want to have Reference Transactions enabled on your PayPal account.  This allows you to process future orders for existing customers who have 'stored' a Credit Card on a previous order.  When processing new orders you/your customer will no longer need the originally used card, just select to 'Use Stored Card'.

However, you're cart/custom code will need to support Reference Transactions in order for this to work.